# js oop style working in chrome but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, oop, firefox

I have this script and it runs fine in chrome (and in JS online validators) but firefox throws me this error:

screen.initialize is not a function

Is this syntax somehow not in accordance with standards?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    screen = new Screen('t543f3r','user1','screen4',5);
    screen.initialize();

}
```

Here is the Screen class:

```
//Our screen object
function Screen(hashKey,username,screenName,layout) {

    this.hashKey = hashKey;
    this.username = username;
    this.screenName = screenName;
    this.layout = layout;

    //this.cacheRefreshInterval = 1000*60*5;
    this.checkLayoutInterval = 1000*60*5; //check for new cache every 5 minutes

}

    Screen.prototype.initialize = function() {

        var self = this;
        console.log('initializing screen '+this.screenName+' (layout is ['+this.layout+']) on player '+this.username+' using key '+this.hashKey);

        var time = self.checkLayoutInterval;
        setTimeout(function(){self.getValidLayout();}, time);
        console.log('getValidLayout() set for '+time);

    }

    Screen.prototype.getValidLayout = function() {

        var self = this;
        var url = self.findBaseUrl(true) + 'getValidLayout/'+self.hashKey;

        jQuery.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: url,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log('successfully fetched the valid screen layout: ['+result+']');
                if (result != self.layout) {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            },
            error: function(result) {
                console.log('there was an error fetching the screen layout');
            },
            complete: function() {

                //setup next check
                var time = self.checkLayoutInterval;
                setTimeout(function(){self.getValidLayout();}, time);
                console.log('next getValidLayout() set for '+time);        

            }                            
        });
    }
```

Comment: Problem here `{{ layout.id }}`, shouldn't it be a string?

Comment: it's always an integer, I replaced the TWIG variables above with the actual values to make the code more clear, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.screen` is a readonly property.  When you assign to it (because you didn't declare your `screen` as a var), the assignment gets ignored.

Comment: oh, reserved I see... is there maybe a problem then in my using 'Screen' as my class (function) name?

Comment: set name of the `screen` variable to something else and it'll work

Comment: I declared it using var and it works fine. But I was wondering if the function name 'Screen' (capital S) is reserved too, I thought maybe it would be trouble in IF or some other browsers?

Comment: 'Screen' with a capital S is in fact predefined, yes.  But your function declaration overrode the predefined value.